# Android design support navigation drawer huge actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, androiddesignsupport

I am implementing the design support navigation drawer and I got it working, but the problem is the toolbar is now huge, it extends over the entire activity height.

The code I am using:
activity_main:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:popupTheme="@style/MenuOverlay" />
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public static Toolbar toolbar;

    public static FragmentManager supportFragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setUpToolbar();
        setUpNavDrawer();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    private void setUpToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    }

    private void setUpNavDrawer() {
        if (toolbar != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main content view must be the first child inside the `DrawerLayout`, so you would have to change your `activity_main` layout to:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/test_toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```